# Multiple X-Axis for Chart In Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server-2008, graph, reporting-services

I have run into a bit of a dilemma in a report I am trying to create using Reporting Services. I have a bar graph and a line graph both of which pertain to the same x-axis value range, however, I am unable to separate the interval at which they plot their y-values.
When I change the category group to rounded values, the bar chart plots at the right interval, but the line graph plots at an obscure interval. And when I change the category group to actual values, the opposite happens. I have the bar graph horizontal axis set to primary and the line graph horizontal axis set to secondary.

**Without Rounded Values**
[image: without rounded]

**With Rounded Values**
[image: with rounded]

Is there anyway I can change the interval at which both these graphs are plotted on the same chart? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two series in your Chart for the bar and line values you're displaying:

[image]

You need to set the **Value axis** for each of these Series:

[image]

If you set one Series to a Primary Value axis and the other to a Secondary Value axis you will get a left and right axis as above and hopefully each Series will have one axis correctly set.

Based on your description you should set up one Category group as appropriate and make sure both Series have the same Category axis value set.

Comment: I have that all done, the intervals of my line graph still is obscured